# How can I resolve the access permission problems with fckeditor?

Tags: php, fckeditor

I have website where I can login , trying to edit the records .. as soon as it displays like this,

```
    Forbidden

    You don't have permission to access /backoffice/processfaculty.php on this server.

    Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I am trying to save data from fckeditor and i don't have any htaccess file on the root ... i also checked permission (755 , tried 777)...

If I edit and save with  simple texts , it works fine.. but if i do it with fckeditor data, it does not.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check you server configuration, you need to have PHP enabled on your server. Look into the error log of your server it will have more information.

This looks like you have a web-firewall installed on your webserver. Temporarily disable it to test if it is causing the issue.

Comment: also it works fine if i enter simple text and save,.. but if i enter large texts using fckeditor it is warning

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i think you should look into:

what is the [mask value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)?

```
umask();
```

> The umask() function changes the file permissions for files.

Comment: As I said, I am using fckeditor, first if i enter 'asdffas' .. no error.. but i enter '<b>asdfdasfdasfadsf</b>' .. gives an error???? i mean with html formatting the above error occur

Comment: so what is the processfaculty.php file